# Misplaced text in EditText android

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

Hi I have an EditText for entering the mail id as below. As I type in the characters, its not visible as show in the screen shot, the letters get shifted slightly upwards.

[image]

Here is the Username layout

```
       <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LayoutUsername "
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".50"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LayoutUsernameText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".60"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/usernameImage"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center|left"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:text="Username :"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="26dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LayoutEditUser"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".40"
            android:background="@drawable/mailedittextbg"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/mailusername"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:cursorVisible="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
                android:hint="John@gmail.com"
                android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textColorHint="#000000"
                android:textSize="24sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

I am not sure where I am going wrong. Please suggest how do I correct it?

Comment: what is the parent layout of this EditText ?
Because you have declared its `height` as `match_parent`

Comment: try giving padding to edittext and also set edittext's height as wrap_content

Comment: Tried! its still the same.How to fix it.I have updated the layout. Please check and reply.

Answer (score 0):

Your Layouts that contains EditTexts have gravity = 0.4, and layouts that contains TextViews have gravity = 0.6 . Try to change this values.

Comment: Tried! its still the same.I have updated the layout. Please check and reply if i need to do any changes

Answer (score 0):

use

```
 android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
```

for `EditText`

```
  <EditText
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
      android:textSize="18sp" />
```

and use `wrap_content` for EditText height and use smaller text size as possible as.

Comment: Tried! its still the same.How to fix it.I have updated the layout. Please check and reply